# Unrecognized function or variable in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot a three dimensional phase portrait of a system of first order differential equations, but I am getting an error message saying I have an unrecognized variable eta. Apart from the three dimensional phase portrait, I also want to plot x(1) versus t, x(2) versus t, and x(3) versus t, all on the same graph. I have commented out this plot command because I'm sure I'm wrong. So, I am looking to plot (i) a 3D phase portrait, and (ii) a time plot of x(1), x(2) and x(3) all on the same graph. Also, the [-0.015,0.015], [-2,2], [-4,4] that you see in the argument of the ode45 are the axes limits of x(1), x(2) and x(3). I am not even sure that the axes limits should be placed there. Could someone please help? Thank you.

```
[t,x] = ode45(@eqx3, eta, omega, [-0.015,0.015], [-2,2], [-4,4], initcond);
global eta omega
eta = 0.05;
omega = 25;
%tspan = [0,50]
initcond = [1, 0.5, -0.4]


%subplot(211)
%plot(t, x(:,1), t,x(:,2),'--',x(:,3),'--');
%xlabel('t')

subplot(212)
plot(x(:,1), x(:,2), x(:,3))
xlabel('x1')
ylabel('x2')
zlabel('x3')

function xdot = eqx3(t,x,eta,omega)
  global eta omega
  xdot = zeros(3,1);
  xdot(1) = -(2*eta*omega + 1)*x(1) + x(2) - 1;
  xdot(2) = -(2*eta*omega + (omega^2))*x(1) + x(3) + 2;
  xdot(3) = -(omega^2)*x(1) + x(2) - 1;
  %xdot =[xdot(1);xdot(2);xdot(3)];
end
```

Comment: You are defining `initcond` after calling `ode45`. Move it to the first line in your program. Same thing with `eta` and `omega`.

Comment: Also, using `global` should not be necessary and it is usually frowned upon. You are already passing `eta` and `omega` as function arguments to `eqx3`, so no need to declare them as `global` variables.

Comment: Hi. I moved initcond to the first line of the code (that was a pretty silly mistake) and commented out global eta omega, but the error "Unrecognized function or variable eta" is still there. A good guide to solving this problem can be found at https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/416516-3d-phase-portrait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code needed some clean up to

- Remove globals,
- Define variables before using them ,
- Pass the right parameters to the ODE equation.
- Use an anonymous function `@(t,x) eqx3(t,x,eta, omega)` to package the ODE parameters with the function,
- Use `plot3` for 3D plotting of the phase portrait.

This is the result that I came up with:

```
eta = 0.05;
omega = 25;
tspan = [0,50];
initcond = [1, 0.5, -0.4]
[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x) eqx3(t,x,eta, omega), tspan, initcond);

plot3(x(:,1), x(:,2), x(:,3))
xlabel('x1')
ylabel('x2')
zlabel('x3')

function xdot = eqx3(t,x,eta,omega)
  xdot = zeros(3,1);
  xdot(1) = -(2*eta*omega + 1)*x(1) + x(2) - 1;
  xdot(2) = -(2*eta*omega + (omega^2))*x(1) + x(3) + 2;
  xdot(3) = -(omega^2)*x(1) + x(2) - 1;
end
```

which produces

[image]

Comment: Kavka, I just ran your code, and it works beautifully. Muchos gracias.